# Put Multiple DIVs Side-by-Side and Vertical Align Middle

Tags: html, css

We are trying to place multiple DIVs side by side.  Very easy, just use FLOAT or INLINE-BLOCK.  The issue with both is you cannot center the data inside the DIV vertically.  Any help would be appreciated!  Needs to be done without a framework.

> Some have suggested this article, but this does not take in to account two or more div's next to each other. [Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

**Option 1:**

```html
<div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; float: left; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #000;"><img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 150px; border: 0;" src="http://unsplash.it/150/100?random" alt="Gaslight" width="150" border="0"></div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; float: left; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #000;"><img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 150px; border: 0;" src="http://unsplash.it/150/100?random" alt="Gaslight" width="150" border="0"></div>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

```html
<div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; display: table-cell;"><img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 150px; border: 0;" src="http://unsplash.it/150/100?random" alt="Gaslight" width="150" border="0"></div>
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #000; display: table-cell;"><img style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 150px; border: 0;" src="http://unsplash.it/150/100?random" alt="Gaslight" width="150" border="0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the second option you've centered the data. What's the problem?

Comment: The second option already works. I just coped to Codepen and all was fine. I'm confused about what you are asking.

Comment: You can solve this by position and translate properties
https://jsfiddle.net/1rmov8Lw/

Comment: centered VERTICALLY is the issue.

Comment: @Swordys, that works!  Is that cross-browser?

Comment: @Dennis Yes it is.

Comment: One issue i found with that - if you have an image in the div, it sizes it down.  I updated the examples above to add an image.  Check your fiddle with that.  thoughts? thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
.file div
{width: 150px; height: 150px;  float: left; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #000;display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/qa8hmaq0/)

Comment: This works well with and without an image in there.  looks like it is css3 and widely accepted too - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If there will be only 1 line of text, you can set `line-height: 150px` for your `<div>`

Also, you can use flex in order to do it easily:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```